# Sound waves dots design

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was looking for a way of creating a wave pattern design with dots (smaller and bigger), building an acoustical panel home. Would be very grateful in case someone has an idea about a possible solution.
or
to be able to rotate the picture to front view,

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? I'm sorry to be blunt, but please specify in what part of the process you are experiencing problems. We are not a tutorial-on-demand site, but we can help you with specific hurdles during the process. Thanks for understanding. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how Stack Exchange works and the [help] to know what is on and off topic here.

Comment: Hi Vincent, sorry not being clear enough. The picture is taken from a side, so I would like to be able to modify the picture to have it full front side instead. Thank you for your time

Comment: I have tried "Transform" -"Transform each"-"scale corners" without success

Comment: In OpenOffice Draw I tried distort Bitmap (slant) function but I still cannot get the perfect aligned front picture

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question, and show us what you are trying to do and trying to achieve. Are you trying to reproduce this image from scratch in Illustrator, or are you just trying to edit this photo so it appears orthogonal? I'm sorry, it's not clear to  me :(

Comment: Do you want to create that effect or you want to make the photo rotate to front view?

Comment: Yes, I would like to rotate the photo to front view if possible (I use a demo version of Adobe Illustrator)

Answer (score 2):

Forget that photo.. you won't get "round" dots when it's transformed. There will *always* be some inconsistency due to the original angle of the photo (there's curvature in photos too). Instead create your own pattern. You've tagged the question with Adobe Illustrator. So, I assume you have that available......

The basics in Illustrator....

- Draw a dashed line with a width profile
- Copy the line and change the stroke weight, then move it to the back
- Copy the line again, change the stroke weight and move it to the front
- Select all 3 lines and choose `Object > Expand Appearance`
- Choose `Object > Blend > Make`
- Choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options` and adjust to your liking
- Choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp` and apply an envelope to bend things...

<sup>Large (kb) gif, it may take a moment...</sup>

[image]

You need to `Expand Appearance` in order to "bake in " the width profile. Otherwise the blend may be a bit "wonky", at least in Illustrator CS6. It may be better in Illustrator CC, I didn't bother testing (prefer to work in CS6).

These are merely **basic** steps. You undoubtedly *will* need to tweak and alter for your own use case.

Comment: Never known that a blend can include more than one 'keyframe'. Thanks, Scott!

Comment: @Vincent. Absolutely! As many as you want. You merely have to watch the stacking order. Blends are applied back to front. So, odd stacking can result in odd blends.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what try to build :)

Comment: @TTy If Scott's answer solved your problem, please consider ticking it as the 'accepted answer'. This tells later visitors that the answer actually helped you, and it's good for site statistics. It gives you a bit of rep, to boot. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Scott. Can I draw your attention to [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii) on meta? We are trying to decrease the amount of lazy 'tutorial-on-demand' questions on the site, and one of the early signs is that answering them isn't a good idea. I'd appreciate your input on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent While I appreciate the ask... I'm kind of past helping this site formulate how it wants to handle any matter internally given my past experience with staff here. My input isn't valued in that respect as I see it.

Comment: I understand. I regret your decision, but I understand. I didn't want to have the discussion take place without at least alerting you that it was.